# ExpandableListView не работает во вложенном ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать скролл активности. ExpandableListView элементы скроллятся, а вот шапка, что я подключил, отдельно не хочет.
Код разметки:
activity_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_expandable_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Инициативное поручение" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Срок:22.12.2017" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Прошу принять Прошу принять Прошу принять Прошу принять" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="тест" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="-16dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

    private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
    int group) {
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                }
            }
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
        if (height < 10)
            height = 200;
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();



}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]